# A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client

Tags: asp.net, html-encode

I'm getting the above exception when I'm trying to submit a form in ASP.NET.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client) post was really helpful but even after setting `ValidateRequest="false"` I get this error only for "&#" combination. This specific combination is required since we are using Norwegian characters.

And I have set `httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"` in `web.config` as well.

Comment: is working to me fine, and not get errors even when I send this characters. Maybe you make some redirect and you do not have place the validaterequest to all page. Better try to add it to web.config.

Comment: Yes you were correct. It works when I add it to web.config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, from the comments, I make it also as an answer.

Place the `ValidateRequest="false"` on the `web.config` to prevent the case that its hit on a forgotten page with out this declaration.

```
<pages validateRequest="false" ... >
```

Comment: This worked for me, and you along with this you should have httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" in web.config file.